# Post data with Ajax.BeginForm to a controller action having full site name

Tags: partial-views, jquery-dialog, ajax.beginform

I want to Post the data from a partial view opening in jQuery dialog to a controller action with full name, like below:

Instead of this:

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("**SendMail**", "**Ui**", (new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "email-dialog", OnSuccess = "onEmailSuccess" })))

I want below:

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("**http://www.MyWebsite.com/Ui/SendMail**", (new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "email-dialog", OnSuccess = "onEmailSuccess" })))

Any idea ?

Comment: Any idea how to do this guys ?